# How to retrieve Velocity data that's used for Azure Dev-Ops Analytics Velocity Dashboard Widget?

Tags: azure-devops, odata, powerbi

I want to retrieve the backend data that's used to specifically drive the Azure DevOps Analytics Velocity Dashboard Report [Committed and Completed Points for each interaction]. I would like to pull this data either using OData feed or the Visual Studio Team Services (Beta) in order to create custom PowerBI reports

[1] Example of the report I'm trying to pull the data from can be found here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/analytics/_img/velocity-ax-catalog.png?view=vsts

Answer (score 2):

Why you have to retrieve the data? You can directly create Power BI reports using Analytics views.

Please see [What are Analytics views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/analytics/what-are-analytics-views?view=vsts) for details.

> When using the Power BI Data Connector, these same default views
>   appear in the Navigator dialog. The view you select determines the set
>   of records, fields, and history which are loaded into Power BI.
>
> Default Analytics views work well for customers with small datasets.
>   To learn more, see Default Analytics views.
>
> If the default Analytics views do not meet your needs, you can create
>   custom views to fine-tune the records, fields, and history returned to
>   Power BI.

Please see below links for more information:

- [Simplify creation of your Power BI reports using Analytics views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/analytics/what-are-analytics-views?view=vsts#simplify-creation-of-your-power-bi-reports-using-analytics-views)
- [Create an Analytics view in Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/analytics/analytics-views-create?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav)
- [Power BI integration overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/overview?view=vsts)

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'm totally aware of the different kinds of connectors and how to retrieve the data; i was asking more of a more specific question, if it was possible to emulate the specific odata field/view that VSTS/Azure Dev-ops uses to generate the Velocity report. Right now it sends a basic view of data, but Microsoft has to do computations to create the Velocity report

Comment: Cannot find a way to retrieve the Velocity data directly, however you can get the original data from specific work item fields via REST API : [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=vsts-rest-4.1)

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT hey, you meant we are unable to retrieve Velocity Data directly from Azure DevOps using OData and you suggesting to use REST API? Is this still valid as of now?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate the Velocity report by using the "Stories - All history" view. You would need to modify the view to track daily history and then use the Iteration start date/Iteration end date along with the "date" column to filter out the Committed and Completed data.

Comment: Could you provide your measure to calculate the velocity based on iteration start and end dates? I am currently struggling with it.... Thanks :)