# Replicate Velocity (AzureDevops Calculation) in PowerBI

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi

[image]

Is that possible to replicate the **Velocity Calculation** in Power BI? I tried to look for the field in Analytics View, but couldn't find any columns that bring this calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can only add fields that already exist, we could check this [doc: Work item field index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/work-item-field?view=azure-devops#alphabetical-index)
 to get all work item field.

We cannot find a way to retrieve the Velocity data directly, however you can get the original data from specific work item fields via REST API [Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), then check the history.

You could also check this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446311/how-to-retrieve-velocity-data-thats-used-for-azure-dev-ops-analytics-velocity-d).

Comment: Hi @Vito Liu-MSFT, let me see if I understood: there is no field that contain this data right? 
I have the data from the API in my database, but how Velocity is calculated?

Comment: Hi @AnnaLuizaDeLisbôa, Yes, this is not field that contain the data, we could check the work item history data via the API I shared before and then get Velocity through calculation