# Velocity chart in Azure devops - degrees of completed late (colour chart)

Tags: azure-devops, sprint

Is it possible to configure the completed late bar in the Azure-devops velocity chart such that the degree of completed late becomes evident? This would mean that stories completed late by one sprint is displayed in another colour than stories completed late by three sprints f.ex.

Image of velocity chart can be seen in this post as an example: [Replicate Velocity (AzureDevops Calculation) in PowerBI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66647577/replicate-velocity-azuredevops-calculation-in-powerbi)

It seems like the default velocity chart is not open to be configured like the above, so the question is really if a manual query has to be created or if anybody has experience with this.